# Javascript: passing data from local to global

Tags: javascript, arrays, amazon-s3, push

I am practicing AWS-S3 bucket and passing data from local to global scope. It's an simple Javascript concept. I have array of strings value which I am getting from S3 bucket. I can see my data when I console it. I am trying pass this data to global scope. I tried push method, spread operator but it did not work. Global scope gives me empty array. I don't get what I am doing wrong.

I get data from S3 bucket like this

```
["182363", "j9292092", "20282"]
```

I want pass my data to global variable exactly this.

**this is my piece of code**

```
  const allSKU = []
  await s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack);
    // else console.log(data.Body.toString('utf-8')); // I can see the data
    const allSku = data.Body.toString('utf-8')
    //console.log(allSku);
    allSKU.push(allSku)
  });


  console.log(allSKU); // give me empty arrays
```

Comment: `s3.getObject` is not returning promise, for us to use await. you can try `const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise()`

Comment: Thanks @BaluVyamajala. I was questioning myself about my js skills :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when passing callback method, await has no effect as method is not returning a promise

```
s3.getObject(params, function (err, data) => {})
```

we can return a promise, by calling .promise() on most of the AWS v2 SDK methods.

```
   const data = await s3.getObject(params).promise()
```

Comment: Need little help @Balu, Do you know how to retrieve data from s3 bucket as arrays set of number. I want output like this [1122, 23456, 11345]

Comment: you mean each file? when we read s3 object, we will get a Buffer, we need to convert into string.

Comment: I figured it out :D